# how to get more number of upvotes on an answer?

Tags: discussion, up-votes, answer-quality

I've been actively participating on SO for last 3 months and I am now able to answer questions well. Although, I noticed that questions or answer will get upvotes only for a short period of time maybe because they will move down the queue in questions list so visited by few visitors.

I was wondering how an answer can get hundreds of votes. I haven't got more than 13 as of now although I've answered with full explanation of the topic.

Will you please give some tips on how to get more number of votes?

Comment: Exposure to the question or answer can help (or hurt)...there's really not much in the way of advice anyone could offer to give your answer(s) more votes.

Comment: Other than the details in the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), it's fairly random. Primarily, they're questions that people find intriguing and/or especially useful.

Comment: @Makoto, sorry I meant answers not questions, and I don't have much problem with English grammar :)

Comment: @Prasad actually, the answer would apply either way; it is primarily by attention that answers get votes (up or down), and answers primarily get their attention through their question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Do nothing*

If you are providing good answers, you should not do anything else. Except, perhaps, share links to especially good questions and answers in social media (but don't spam!)

You can't predict what will always draw lots of votes. And honestly, 13 isn't a bad number of up votes for an answer.

Note that some tags tend to get more attention than others, and therefore more votes. Also, keep in mind that you will get residual votes over time.

I tend to be happy if I get a handful of up votes. and my answers with larger numbers of votes, well... if it weren't for my vanity, I would probably think about deleting them, as I'm not especially proud of them.

Comment: thanks for the answer :) Even I delete my answers if I'm not proud of them :)

Comment: @PrasadKharkar don't! only delete answers if you know they bring nothing to the question

Comment: I agree with @Jan wholeheartedly here.

Comment: @JanDvorak, yeah exactly, sometimes it happens that questions is misread and and a correct but out of scope answer is provided. I delete these kind of answers.

Answer (score 3):

It is really not easy to get the rep. As what you say, answers will be moved down the queue. So what we can do is to promote the link what you answer but not spam. Though i have only 1 rep, i don't care, the answer that can help others is the most important.

Comment: like this one helped me :)